# How to run functions in random order?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, random

I want to run functions with random order. It looks like "shuffle" function which shuffle a variables list.

Input:

```
def a():
    print('a')

def b():
    print('b')

def c():
    print('c')

shuffle([a,b,c])
```

This is output what I want:

```
a
b
c
```

or

```
a
c
b
```

or

```
c
b
a
```

or etc
How to run functions with random order?

Comment: `from random import shuffle` ... Seems like you're practically there.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet? You should post that too.  I'm thinking make a dictionary with the keys being integers and the values being function references, then look up a function in the dictionary using a random integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is an in-place operation. So you need to keep the list separately and shuffle it.

```
import random

functions = [a, b, c]
random.shuffle(functions)
```

Now, the functions are shuffled and you just have to execute them

```
for func in functions:
    func()
```

---

You can probably store this in a function and do it like this

```
def run_functions_in_random_order(*funcs):
    functions = list(funcs)
    random.shuffle(functions)
    for func in functions:
        func()

run_functions_in_random_order(a, b, c)
```

---

Or you can simply use the functions in closures, like this

```
def run_functions_in_random_order(*funcs):
    def run():
        functions = list(funcs)
        random.shuffle(functions)
        for func in functions:
            func()
    return run

random_exec = run_functions_in_random_order(a, b, c)

random_exec()
random_exec()
random_exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or make a list and take random:

```
import random  

def a():
    print('a')

def b():
    print('b')

def c():
    print('c')  

my_list = [a, b, c] 
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Comment: When in a loop, this might(\*) call the same function multiple times. (\*) The chance that each one is called only once 3 times in a row is actually too small (2 out of 9 if I'm right) to call it "might".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do. Basically what **thefourtheye** has suggested. [Run this Code](https://repl.it/DsMk/0)

```
from random import shuffle

def a():
    print('a')

def b():
    print('b')

def c():
    print('c')

def main():
    lis = [a,b,c]

    shuffle(lis)

    for i in lis:
        i()
```